# Can't seem to add a Service as provider to app.component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2

I need to add the provider to share a variable with app.component.ts, because I'm looking for the logged user data in real time in my app, but I can't seem to add the provider to the constructor, I keep getting the following error.

> Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase
>    App.initializeApp()

Here's a snapshot of my code:

app.component.ts :

```
import { UsersServiceProvider } from '../providers/users-service/users-service';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
})

export class MyApp {
    @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;
    rootPage:any = InicioPage;

    constructor(public userServices : UsersServiceProvider) //another imports too
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
    var config = {
         //some config for app and firebase
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    var that = this;
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
        // Need to set variable on userServices HERE
        }
    })
};
```

user-service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {AlertController , Platform} from 'ionic-angular'
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class UsersServiceProvider {

public currentUser : any;
 constructor(private platform: Platform, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public http: Http) {
}

setCurrentUser(user){
  this.currentUser = user; // WANT TO SET IT HERE
}

}
```

Everything is also OK at the app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you call your `UsersServiceProvider`'s `setCurrentUser()` method from `MyApp`:

```
this.userServices.setCurrentUser(user);
```

Here it is in context

```
import {
  UsersServiceProvider
} from '../providers/users-service/users-service';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
})

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) navCtrl: Nav;
  rootPage: any = InicioPage;

  constructor(public userServices: UsersServiceProvider) //another imports too
  platform.ready().then(() => {
    statusBar.styleDefault();
    splashScreen.hide();
  });
  var config = { //some config for app and firebase
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var that = this;
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.userServices.setCurrentUser(user); // Need to set variable on userServices HERE
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: I really want to call the setCurrentUser, but I just can't add the provider to the constructor because I get the error in firebase like described :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Firebase but have you tried to add the service in app.module.ts? You have to do that before you can inject it on any class. It should like this:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [],
imports: [],
providers: [UsersServiceProvider]
})
```